# SwiftUI Menu top-to-bottom order varies depending on context?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

I think I know the answer to this, but I'll pose it as a question and give my answer, since it was a bit puzzling to me and it took me a little while to figure out.

I'm just starting to use `Menu`'s in SwiftUI. In my first application of them I used them in the nav bar of my app.

```
            Menu {
                ForEach(pickers, id: \.mediaPickerUIDisplayName) { picker in
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.sheetToShow = .picker(picker)
                    }) {
                        Text(picker.mediaPickerUIDisplayName)
                    }.enabled(picker.mediaPickerEnabled)
                }
            } label: {
                SFSymbolIcon(symbol: .plusCircle)
            }
```

And it looked good.

[image]

Then, I changed the context in which this same code was used. Instead of being used from the nav bar, I used it in the center of a screen. And instead I saw:

[image]

I was disconcerted in that the top-to-bottom ordering of items in the list had changed.

Answer (score 6):

[UPDATE]
In iOS16 (beta) at the time of writing you can now use the new modifier `.menuOrder(.fixed)`. That will keep the order of your items, well, fixed and the name implies…

Yup. This is the ‘native’ behavior which I personally find extremely bad. Imagine you have the delete button on the bottom and suddenly without any warning the order changes only because the element has moved above /bellow the midline.
Muscle memory will kick in and the users will get extremely confused.
This is an omission with catastrophic consequences.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Then I noticed that the order relative to the activating button is the same. So, it seems the order of menu items is context dependent.

[image]

Comment: Correct. Same for menus in UIKit, not just SwiftUI.